# Download and delete remote files using lftp

Tags: lftp

I can't figure out how to download AND delete remote files using lftp using the command line only.

Using bash is also OK.

What are the flags and the full command line? All I can figure out is the mirror command, but that leaves files on the remote server.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally figured it out... use the flag "--Remove-source-files" with mirror and all is well.

Like this:

```
lftp sftp://${username}@${host} -u ${username},${password} -e "mirror --Remove-source-files --verbose ${remote_dir} ${local_dir}; bye"
```

Comment: Does it remove local files or remote files?

Comment: Remote, "source" is where you originally get the files.

Comment: This will remove files but not dirs. In the man page there is an --Remove-source-dirs option. But it's not recognized : mirror: unrecognized option '--Remove-source-dirs'

Comment: REASON: you need lftp >= 4.7 to use this option.